# How to disable infinite looping in slick lightbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am using slick-lightbox plugin https://github.com/jongacnik/slick-lightbox.
I have a gallery of images.
I am trying to do this now:-

```
$('.slider-lightbox').slickLightbox({
    navigateByKeyboard: true,
    slick:{infinite:'false'}
});
```

But this is not disabling the infinite looping.

HTML code

```
<div class="image-gallery-content">
    <ul class="slider-lightbox">
        <li class="video active">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KCI8Wb4KTG8" width="400px" target="_blank">
               <img src="images/community/img2.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
            <img class="play-btn" src="images/video-icon.png">
        </li>
        <li class="image active">
            <a href="images/community/img3.jpg" target="_blank">
               <img src="images/community/img3.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="image active">
            <a href="images/community/img1.jpg" target="_blank">
               <img src="images/community/img1.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass a proper (=boolean) `false` into `slick`, not a string `'false'`:

```
$('.slider-lightbox').slickLightbox({
    navigateByKeyboard: true,
    slick: {infinite:false}
});
```

Comment: This is not working very well.It does not disable the next on the last image instead it disables it on the  next image.

Comment: Seems to be an issue of `slick` (incorrectly detecting the last item to scroll in this case). Actually, there's a LOT of issues related to it in the [slick's github](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+infinite). Can you create a codepen version of your code?